# percentage count by group using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

with a data frame `df` like below

```
df <- data.frame(colors = c("red", "blue", "green", "red", "red" , "blue"))
```

I can find out the count per color using dplyr as follows

```
df %>%
  group_by(color) %>%
    summarise(count = n())
```

Instead of count I need to find the percentage count for each color - how to go about it using dplyr ?

Comment: Use prop.table and multiply by 100

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can either pipe this to a `mutate( prop = count / sum(count) )` or directly within `summarise` with `nrow(.)`. Something like this:

```
df %>%
  group_by(colors) %>%
  summarise(count = n() / nrow(.) )
```

or

```
df %>%
  group_by(colors) %>%
  summarise(count = n() ) %>%
  mutate( prop = count / sum(count) )
```

Comment: can you give some details of the dot(.) used in  `nrow(.)`

Comment: the `.` stands for the whole data frame (`df` here)